# Why are the borders/edges not generated properly in this 2 color perlin noise texture? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am generating textures using perlin noise, and i make it so the texture has only 2 colors (if the value is above a limit its white else its black). So the problem is that the color of the texture on the edges is sometimes not right, and i cant seem to find out why. I am adding the code here, so u can check it out easily in any unity project, and i also try to send a picture:[borderproblem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es8xk.png)

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour{
 public int mapWidth = 256;
 public int mapHeight = 256;
 public int xCount = 3;
 public int yCount = 3;

 void Start()
 {
     //create number of textures
     for (int y = 0; y < yCount; y++)
         for (int x = 0; x < xCount; x++)
         {
             CreateTexture(x * mapWidth, y * mapHeight);
         }
 }

 void CreateTexture(int posX, int posY)
 {
     //Creating gameObject to hold the texture
     GameObject gObject = new GameObject(posX + "; " + posY);
     gObject.transform.parent = this.transform;
     gObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(posX, posY);

     //adding SpriteRenderer and create and set a texture for it
     Texture2D mapTexture = new Texture2D(mapWidth, mapHeight);
     SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = gObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
     Vector2 mapSize = new Vector2(mapWidth, mapHeight);
     spriteRenderer.sprite = Sprite.Create(mapTexture, new Rect(Vector2.zero, mapSize), Vector2.zero, 1f);

     //generate texture values
     GenerateValues(mapTexture, posX, posY);
 }

 public void GenerateValues(Texture2D mapTexture, int posX, int posY)
 {
     //create a color array for the texture pixels
     Color32[] baseColors = new Color32[mapWidth * mapHeight];

     //iterate through all elements of color array
     for (int i = 0, y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
         for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++, i++)
         {
             //calculate value
             bool currentValue = CalculateMapValue(x + posX, y + posY, 100000, 100000);
             //set color based on calculated value
             baseColors[y * mapWidth + x] = currentValue ? Color.black : Color.white;
         }

     // set colors and apply texture
     mapTexture.SetPixels32(baseColors);
     mapTexture.Apply();

 }

 bool CalculateMapValue(int x, int y, float offsetX, float offsetY)
 {
     float xCoord = (float)x / mapWidth * 5f + offsetX;
     float yCoord = (float)y / mapHeight * 5f + offsetY;

     float sample = Mathf.PerlinNoise(xCoord, yCoord);

     return sample <= 0.5f ? true : false;
 }
```

}

EDIT:
made pictures 64x64 so i can see the pixels better, and  i think i found the problem (sort of). i changed the colorization a bit:

```
for (int i = 0, y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++, i++)
        {
            //calculate value
            bool currentValue = CalculateMapValue(x + posX, y + posY, 100000, 100000);
            currentValue = y > x && x % 2 == 0;
            //set color based on calculated value
            baseColors[y * mapWidth + x] = currentValue ? Color.black : Color.white;
        }

    baseColors[mapWidth + 10] = Color.red;
    baseColors[0] = Color.red;
```

And now the textures look like this:

[newpic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OkoY.png)

[single texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kGXi.png)

So what i found is that pixels on the bottom side are visible on the top side (the same with left and right side), but i have no idea why is that, nor how i could fix that. Any ideas?

Comment: Picture and question are unclear. The results look fine to me, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: In the picture i sent there are 9 textures, so if you break the whole thing in 3 parts vertically, you can find the black/white lines on the border of two textures. I'm not sure how else I can say it, they are there

Comment: Ah, I could not make that out on my tablet. That usually comes from bad approximations in the rendering engine that thinks it can see between your planes and renders the skybox

Comment: Do you know how i could fix it? is it pssible at all?

Comment: Oh and  i dont think it is the skybox, the lines are black and white not blu as the skybox, they are black, then at point change to white then back randomly (at least it seems random)

Comment: And i checked it with lower resolution sprites, and they are not one pixel wide, but smaller (how is that even possible?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to add:

```
mapTexture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
```

It was probably set to TextureWrapMode.Repeat by default. Not sure whether this is just a workaround or the actual solution though.

Comment: Ah, that would do it too.